# Unable import as `libraryname/header.h`

Tags: xcode

I keep running into this problem. I have a library and it contains imports like:

```
#include "libraryname/header.h"
```

And when I compile, it says the file cannot be found. If I manually delete the reference to `libraryname` it often works.

```
#include "header.h"
```

However the examples I use often work just fine with original include. I don't understand the different. I have throughly compared differences in my project with the differences in like build settings etc. but can't find out what the difference is.

The `libraryname` does not relate to the folder structure because the file structure of the library is:

```
/libraryname/src/header.h
```

What is the difference in having the nested header? Any points? How can this be fixed?

*I am not sure about the terminologies here which hinders the start to find a answer. Sorry to not give specific examples but I have repeatdly had this problem with Objective-C projects and c libraries as well as C++ project with C++ libraries. I must be missing something!*

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the path to the header files in the **Header Search Paths** field of the Target's Build Settings. The developer of the library you are using should have instructions about what you need to set up for it to work out.

Comment: They are in HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS. I've just tried adding them to USER_HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS and this appears to make a difference? (Although thrown another error)

Comment: Is this on the target or the project build settings, watch out that the target isn't overriding these settings with something incorrect.